# Loading Image from web make application hung

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiimage

I'm loading image from web in my iPhone application. I'm using this image for the image view of Table cell. Few seconds after application launch all images are loaded completely.But scrolling of table is not smooth.There is delay.The scrolling takes place few seconds after gesture. And there is jerking.I'm using this code

```
UIImage *imagefromWeb = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[IconArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
        CGSize newSize= CGSizeMake(45.0,45.0);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
        [imagefromWeb drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
        UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        cell.imageView.image=newImage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code : `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[IconArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` makes the application hanging. Because `dataWithContentsOfURL` method is a synchronous call. You never call such synchronous call on main thread, it will make your UI unresponsive.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    UIImage *imagefromWeb = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[IconArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    CGSize newSize= CGSizeMake(45.0,45.0);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [imagefromWeb drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.imageView.image=newImage;
   });

});
```

There are a lot of opensource library for loading image to tableView and cache them, please check:

1. [**HJCache**](https://github.com/markofjohnson/HJCache)
2. [**SDWebImage**](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)
3. [**LazyTableImages**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 2):

You are loading image synchronously thats why the problem try the following code for asynchronous downloading of the image :

```
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,  0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSURL *imageURL=[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSData *imageData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            [cell setNeedsLayout];

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use uiimageview category that is "sdwebimage" hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Lazy Loading for loading image from URL, Refer the following sample link,

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

hope it will helps you.....